# How can i get the label name of a menubutton-widget

Tags: python, tkinter, label

```
import tkinter as tk
fenster = tk.Tk()
fenster.geometry("500x150")
def Seite_0():
    button = tk.Menubutton(fenster,text="Test",relief= "raised")
    bestaetigen = tk.Button(fenster, text="Weiter", command=lambda: [print(button.cget("text"))])
    Menü = tk.Menu(button,tearoff=0)
    Menü.add_command(label="1")
    button["menu"] = Menü
    button.pack()
    bestaetigen.pack()
    fenster.destroy()
Seite_0()
fenster.mainloop()
```

Expected output:
"1"

Is there any type of command that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the label name of a menubutton-widget

problem can be fix.

in line 13, comment out `#fenster.destroy()`

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot:

[image]